# Change key of a JSON document

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following JSON file that is inserted in MongoDB

```
"entities": [{
    "type": "Location",
    "text": "Marília",
    "relevance": 0.966306,
    "disambiguation": {
      "subtype": [
        "CityTown",
        "City"
      ],
      "name": "Marília",
      "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Marília"
    },
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "type": "Organization",
    "text": "Associação Engenheiros, Arquitetos",
    "relevance": 0.647857,
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

In MongoDB `type` is a reserved word. How do I change the `type` key to `desctype`? I'm working with NodeJS.

I've already tried:

```
data = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/"type"/g, /"desctype"/); 
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

But I have error in:

> JSON.parse: SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong:

You should be using it like this:

```
data = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/type/g, "desctype");
```

However, since you also have a `subtype`, this won't really work.

A better way to do this would be to map through the data to change it's structure like this:

```
data.entities.map(entity => ({ ...entity, desctype: entity.type, type: null }))
```

`...entity` will spread all the properties of the `entity`, we'll create a `desctype` that will be initialized with `entity.type` and then we'll set `type` to `null`.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to manipulate your data structure, I would recommend to use object manipulation functions to achieve this. Here, you can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for that.

Additionally, you can leverage **ES6** way of simplifying the function using [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and further simplify object manipulation using [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) where it spreads all the properties of the object. Over here, `{type, ...rest}` in function **destructures** object into `type` and the other properties are collected in `rest` using the concept of [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

```js
let entities = [{"type":"Location","text":"Marília","relevance":0.966306,"disambiguation":{"subtype":["CityTown","City"],"name":"Marília","dbpedia_resource":"http://dbpedia.org/resource/Marília"},"count":3},{"type":"Organization","text":"Associação Engenheiros, Arquitetos","relevance":0.647857,"count":1}];

entities = entities.map(({type, ...rest}) => ({...rest, desctype:type}));
console.log(entities);
```

Comment: @cale_b - Thank you for your inputs. I have updated the answer to provide basic insights. I hope it clarifies!

Answer (score 1):

fileData.findAndCountAll({
        attrib, whr
    })
        .then(dta => {
            if (dta.count > 0) {
                res.send(dta.rows);
            }
            else {
                var msg = "No record found";
                res.status(404).json({ status: false, message: msg });
            }
        });

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, format your code and and an explanation of how your code helps.

Answer (score 0):

This will replace `type` with `desctype`

```js
let data = {
  "entities": [{
      "type": "Location",
      "text": "Marília",
      "relevance": 0.966306,
      "disambiguation": {
        "subtype": [
          "CityTown",
          "City"
        ],
        "name": "Marília",
        "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Marília"
      },
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "type": "Organization",
      "text": "Associação Engenheiros, Arquitetos",
      "relevance": 0.647857,
      "count": 1
    }
  ]
}


data['entities'] = data['entities'].map(function(i){

  i['desctype'] = i['type'];
  delete i['type'];

  return i

})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lodash [_.mapKeys](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mapKeys) method.

```
const newEntities = entities.map((entity) => {
    _.mapKeys(entity, (value, key) => {
        return (key === 'type') ? 'desctype' : key;
     }
 });
```

Comment: The mapKey method iterate over the object keys and return the new keys.